# Update PlayServices on Genymotion automatically when using snapshot

Tags: android, jenkins, cron, continuous-integration, genymotion

We are using Genymotion-Emulator to run UI-Tests on our Jenkins-CI-Server. To provide a clean test environment to every test project, we use a snapshot which will be used for the tests:

```
VBoxManage snapshot "Phone_4.3" restore "initial"
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "Phone_4.3" &
```

However, it would be nice to have a script or cron job which updates our current emulator snapshots, if a new version of e.g. google play services is available, automatically.

I know how to start the emulator:

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "Phone_4.3" &
```

and how to take a snapshot:

```
VBoxManage snapshot "Phone_4.1" take "initial"
```

Now I need to know, how can I ensure that a running emulator updates the google play services? Is there any way to trigger this from command line or can I write a UI-Test?

Our current approach is to manually update the snapshots.